# Load only specific FontAwesome icons in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Is there a way to only load certain FontAwesome icons? All my clients sites are really slowed down by all the FontAwesome icons, and it would be great to only load the ones I need. I'm using WordPress.

Thanks,
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

You can output your own icon sets using [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select). This site includes FA and other icon sets to build fully customised sets, just be careful mixing icon sets as their icons can be inconsistent in their design.

In this way you will only load the icons you need and you can call them as normal.